# Use DTO field as a key of @CachePut. Not mentioned in method argument

Tags: java, spring, caching

I would like to use caches to take care of a lot of call to external API.

Logic looks like this:

1. Make a call to my custom endpoint with the parameter `banana`
2. Checking cache
3. if cache is not there, check database
4. if it's not in db, make a call to external api
5. save to db, save to cache
6. return

Here is a deal. I made some draft implementation which works but when I'm making a call
to the external API i need to provide not only banana but let's say `100g banana`
which means, If I put annotation @CachePut and point to the parameter as a key. Then in my cache I will save String `100g banana` not banana. Is that possible to save cache by providing key as a field value of the response object? (just banana)
Let's say external json payload goes to the
ProductDTO with fields

- name
- weight
  ...

```
@Cacheable(value = "products", key = "#productName", unless = "#result == null")
    @GetMapping("/prod/{productName}")
    public Product getProductCache(@PathVariable String productName) {
        log.info("Getting product with name {}.", productName);

        Product product = productRepository.getByName(productName);
        log.info("Product in database is:{}", product);
        if (product == null) {
            product = productService.getProductFromExternalApi(productName);
        }

        return product;
    }
```

```
@CachePut(value = "products", key = "#I want product.getName without passing Product as a parameter")
    public Product getProductFromExternalApi(String productName){

        SOME CODE TO BUILD A REQUEST

            productRepository.save(product);

            return product;
    }
```

Btw, I don't get root.target which points to the Controller class rather than Product.
I can ofc make a regex or substring that 100g banana to banana but yea, I wonder if it's possible just directly from the annotation

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use these?

```
@CachePut(value = "products", key = "#p1")
```

Or

```
@CachePut(value = "products", key = "#product.name")
```

Comment: yes. I can not use #product.name because I'm not passing whole Product in argument of the method. It would work if 
`public Product getProductFromExternalApi(Product product){`

#p1 point to the first parameter of the method which is `100g banana` not just `banana`

Comment: In this case, wouldn't it be better to use as a key an attribute that not changes... like an ID?